# Identifying elements that occur within strings in a list

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list, with pipes denoting a hierarchy.

```
l = ['animals|fish|salmon', 'fish|salmon', 'fish', 'animals', 'furniture',
    'animals|big cats|lions', 'animals|birds|fisher bird']
```

I want to return a list with all the entries that are not redundant:

```
l = ['animals|fish|salmon', 'animals|big cats|lions',
     'animals|birds|fisher bird', 'furniture']
```

I tried various variations of sorting the list by length and then using the "any" keyword to find elements that were contained within one of these entries.

```
l2 = paths.sort(key=len)
for i in l2:
    if any(i in j for j in l if i != j):
...
```

But this wasn't really successful. Can anyone recommend a better way of approaching this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you overwritten the `|` operator for string? I just get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'`.

Comment: Whoops, sorry -- I put the pipes in the wrong location. I just fixed this problem. (The pipes should be in the string.) Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: what happens if you have say `l = ['animals|fish', 'fish|salmon']`?

Comment: I hadn't considered this. `l = ['animals|fish', 'fish|salmon']` should be returned.

Comment: What is the expected output for input `['animals', 'animals|quadrupeds', 'aliens', 'aliens|quadrupeds']`? Because Ashwini's answer produces `['animals', 'animals|quadrupeds', 'aliens']`, but mine produces `['animals|quadrupeds', 'aliens|quadrupeds']`.

Comment: `['animals|quadrupeds', 'aliens|quadrupeds']` would be the preferred output. Essentially for a list of A|B|C, only keep A if there is not A|B and only keep A|B if there is not A|B|C, where all the letters are potential nouns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
l = ['animals|fish|salmon', 'fish|salmon', 'fish', 'animals', 'furniture',
    'animals|big cats|lions', 'animals|birds|fisher bird']

def simplify (data):
    data = ['|{}|'.format (e) for e in data]
    return [e [1:-1] for e in data if all (e is other or e not in other for other in data) ]

print (simplify (l) )
```

It prints:

```
['animals|fish|salmon', 'furniture', 'animals|big cats|lions', 'animals|birds|fisher bird']
```

---

What I do:

First step: put pipes at the beginning and end of each item `'|{}|'.format` (to avoid conflicts with e.g. `fish` and `fisher bird`.

Second step: Filter the list, throwing away all items which are subpaths of another (`e not in other`) except themselves (`e is other or`). I also trim again the additional pipes (`e [1:-1]`)

Comment: Basically I throw away all elements which are a sub-path of another element. Is that what you want?

Comment: @BenjaminToueg Ah ok. I will add some explanation.

Comment: I agree it is dense. Very clever, though. Your edit makes it clearer. Can you also put the 'it prints' line with the 4-space leading notation? IMO it's less readable in backticks.

Comment: I didn't know the existence of the `all` function!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.

Here I am using a `set` to keep track of already seen items. I loop over each item, split it at whitespaces first and then at `|`, and next step is to check if any of the item in that list is not present in `seen` set or not, if yes then store that string in `out` list and the items of the list are added to the `seen` set.

```
lis = ['animals|fish|salmon', 'fish|salmon', 'fish', 'animals', 'furniture',
    'animals|big cats|lions', 'animals|birds|fisher bird']
seen = set()
out = []
for x in lis:
    items = [z for y in x.split() for z in y.split('|')]
    if any(y not in seen for y in items):
        seen.update(items)
        out.append(x)
print out        

#['animals|fish|salmon', 'furniture', 'animals|big cats|lions', 'animals|birds|fisher bird']
```

Comment: Your answer and mine produce different results for e.g. input `['animals', 'animals|quadrupeds', 'aliens', 'aliens|quadrupeds']`. But I am not sure which one OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier I asked "what happens if you have say `l = ['animals|fish', 'fish|salmon']`?" And I was bored so I've fiddled around with a solution to return all unique chains in full.

now `['animals|fish', 'fish|salmon'] -> ['animals|fish|salmon']`

and `['animals|fish|trout', 'fish|salmon'] -> ['animals|fish|salmon','animals|fish|trout']`

You can create a Node for each species containing a list of child species, and its parent species. For each animal individual animal in the list you can create a node. For each string in the list, you link the child animal to the parent animal in-front of it.

When you're done you print the hierarchy of all animals that do not have a parent.

```
class SpeciesNode(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.parent = None
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
    def add_node(self,s_node):
        if not s_node in self.children:
            s_node.parent = self
            self.children.append(s_node)
    def get_branches(self):
        if len(self.children) == 0:
            yield self.name
        else:
            for child in self.children:
                for branch in child.get_branches():
                    yield self.name + '|' + branch
```

Now you can define a function to convert a list of hierarchies into a list of nodes.

```
def get_s_nodes(animal_list):
    s_nodes = {}
    for hierarchy in animal_list:
        h_list = hierarchy.split('|')
        parent = None
        for species in h_list:
            if not species in s_nodes.keys():
                s_nodes[species] = SpeciesNode(species)
            if parent is not None:
                s_nodes[parent].add_node(s_nodes[species])
            parent = species
    return s_nodes.values()
```

Finally convert this back to a list of strings

```
def get_animal_list(s_nodes):
    animal_kingdom = []
    for node in s_nodes:
        if node.parent is None:
            for branch in child.get_branches():
                animal_kingdom.append(branch)
    return animal_kingdom
```

so:

```
>>> l = ['animals|fish|salmon', 'fish|salmon','fish|trout', 'salmon|salmon eggs', 'fish', 'animals',
         'furniture', 'animals|big cats|lions', 'animals|birds|fisher bird']
>>> get_animal_list(get_s_nodes(l))
['animals|fish|salmon|salmon eggs', 'animals|fish|trout', 'animals|big cats|lions', 'animals|birds|fisher bird', 'furniture']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the definition of "redundant" isn't 100% clear here. Your post seems to indicate that if all of the text in one entry appears in another that's redundant, but I don't think that's really what you mean. For example `['fish', 'fishers']` should probably not be reduced to just `['fishers']` even though `'fish' in 'fishers' == True`.

I'm guessing what you want is closer to this:

```
def is_redundant(a, b):
   """Is a redundant given b?"""
   a_parts = set(a.split('|'))
   b_parts = set(b.split('|'))
   return len(a_parts.intersect(b_parts) == len(b_parts)
```

Here's a simple (but inefficient) solution:

```
for item in l:
    l = filter(lambda x: not is_redundant(x, item), l)
```